# Postfix: relay mail to smart host for specifc users

Tags: email, smtp, postfix

Currently i have a VPS that has a host of email accounts on for several domains.

most are simple and have all local mailboxes.

but i have one user that wants to have a hosted exchange account but leave all the others as they are.

So what i would like to do is:

Domain1.com
- Deliver all mail localy (as it currently does)

Domain2.com
- user1@domain2.com -> send to smart.host1.com
- all others treated as local.

then there is also a possibilty that i could have:

Domain3.com
- user1@domain3.com -> send to smart.host1.com
- user2@domain3.com -> send to smart.host2.com
- all others treated as local.

it also may use useful if i could specify a outgoing smarthost per domain name.

Im sure this has to be possible.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport` in `main.cf`

```
#/etc/postfix/transport
domain1.com     local:
user1@domain2.com       smtp:smart.host1.com:25
domain2.com             local:
user1@domain3.com       smtp:smart.host1.com:25
user2@domain3.com       smtp:smart.host2.com:25
domain3.com             local:
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work, Currently i have got 
relayhost = outbound.smarthost.com would this effect any of the above?

Comment: Please see [postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) `transport_maps` override `relayhost` parameter. U can have a `*   smtp:outbound.smarthost.com:25` line in your transport file as a workaround

Comment: It's necessary to run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` and restart the service or at least invoke `service postfix reload` after creating `transport` and changing `main.cf`.